# PCL Load assembly at runtime in memory

Tags: c#, memory, stream, .net-assembly, portable-class-library

Background:
I am trying to create an app where users can create a Portable Class Library (PCL) and upload it into my software.  Since my software is a client/server architecture, I am looking to do the client on windows, ios, android and windows phone (Xamarin will be used for the mobile devices).  I am trying to create a PCL for all these clients to use.
Problem:
PCL does not have as many overloaded static methods to dynamically load an assembly and keep it in memory. I currently have the Assembly as a Stream when I download it over the network and want to deserialize it into an Assembly.  Assembly.Load only takes in a string of the AssemblyName (which has to be located on disk).

Is there a workaround, another library or another option to load an assembly from a Stream in memory?

```
public static List<DeviceInformation> DeCompileDevicePackage(Stream ZipStream)
    {
        List<Assembly> packageassemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(ZipStream);
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            using (Stream zipfile = entry.Open())
            {
                switch (entry.FullName.Substring(entry.Name.Length - 4))
                {
                    case ".dll":
                        //TestPortable.dll is located in the same folder as the exectuable and this PCL library
                        AssemblyName assemblyname = new AssemblyName("TestPortable, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
                        //I want to do something similar below but I want to use zipfile Stream instead of AssemblyName
                        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyname);
                        packageassemblies.Add(assembly);
                        break;
                    default:
                        //ignore files
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

You can ignore the zip stuff because I just unzip it after it comes over the network.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the relevant code snippet to demonstrate what you are doing and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry @devlincarnate, I edited my post to show some code I want to do.